# How do I add a caption to a table within a minipage?

Tags: knitr, xtable

I am using Knitr to generate two tables side by side on a two column layout (ACM sigproc).

```
\begin{table*}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
<<results='asis'>>=
print(xtable(o.stats.sel.op, caption='Original', label='table:rando'),
   include.rownames=FALSE, floating=FALSE,  size='\\small',
   sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})
@
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
<<results='asis'>>=
print(xtable(r.stats.sel.op, caption='Randoop', label='table:randr'),
  include.rownames=FALSE, floating=FALSE,size='\\small',
  sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})
@
\end{minipage}
\bigskip
\caption {Operators}
\label{tbl:operators}
\end{table*}
```

My problem is that the captions of child tables (Original and Generated) are not visible (they are not generated in the tex file because apparently it wont be generated if floating is false). Is there any way I can get them to show up?

Comment: In pure LaTeX, this would be straight-forward.

Comment: @Werner that hint was very useful, I was able to use the caption package to accomplish it. Thanks (I used \caption*{} just outside the xtable)

Comment: You can also use `\captionof{table}{...}`.

Comment: `begin{minipage}[h]` minipage doesn't have an `h` option. (But you do not nee minipage at all as far as I can see)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments